# Zend_auth - Doctrine 2.2 - autoloading pbl

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-auth, zend-session

I've updating lib Doctrine 2.0 to 2.2 with Bisna lib. It works just fine, but i've got a problem with Zend_Session / zend_auth when `Zend_Session::start()` is called (into `Boostrap.php`). I've got a fatal error due to User's Proxy stocked in session.

```
> Zend_Session_Exception Object
(
    [_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
    [message:protected] => Zend_Session::start() - /home/site/dev.full-estudio.com/library/Zend/Loader.php(Line:146): Error #2 include_once(): Failed opening 'Studio/Domain/Proxy/__CG__/Studio/Domain/Entity/ESecurityStudioUser.php' for inclusion
```

Class Name

```
Studio\Domain\Proxy\__CG__\Studio\Domain\Entity\ESecurityStudioUser
```

The real path of this class is

```
Studio\Domain\Proxy\__CG__StudioDomainEntityESecurityStudioUser
```

Configuration Doctrine Proxy:

```
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.autoGenerateClasses = true
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.namespace           = "Studio\Domain\Proxy"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.dir                 = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Studio/Domain/Proxy"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew's answer points in the right direction.

Doctrine 2.2.0 does not seem to like more than a single level of proxy namespace (at least in the context of a ZF1.x bootstrap process -- I encountered it in the same exact context as bastien).

So

```
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.namespace = "Fancy\Ns\Proxy"
```

breaks autoloading of proxies, while

```
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.namespace = "Proxy"
```

works just fine.  (In fact, you can comment out the config line, and Bisna will use "Proxy" as the default).

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem... see here:-

http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/334c3136ccf21630

It seems that the bisna lib does not fully support doctrine 2.2 :(

Comment: ya, Bisna is ok when i try to get an association domain, this is proxy returned and no pbl to put/ get data. The pbl is link to Session used convention Class Zf1 ... :(